# imgur style non-flash uploader in .net...how do they do it?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I am trying to build a file uploader.  I already have a working multi-select uploader using Flash, which works well.

I also need to build a basic uploader, which is cross platform and offers good usability.  I like what Imgur uses for their basic uploader, but I don't know how it works.  This is the URL:
http://imgur.com/?noFlash

They offer the ability to select files one at a time, then have an upload button which uploads all of them.

Any idea how this works?  I'm looking to build something similar in .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the new HTML5 attribute, [`multiple`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html#input.file.attrs.multiple):

```
<input type="file" id="file" multiple="multiple" name="file">
```

Comment: Ahhh....alas, if only HTML had enough market share.  I assume they detect if a browser is HTML5 capable, and enable these controls, otherwise using a more basic control in older (or non-compliant) browsers.

Comment: It's just a new attribute. It will gracefully degrade into a single file upload.